# What ...[] means in Flutter Cloud Firestore | Firebase?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I am still learning and I have a question. What excatly in flutter means? -

```
`'...[]'`
```

Just wondering.. When im using 'for in' to fetch data from my database I have to use this '...[]' but why? What does it doing?

I couldn't find answer in the google, probably im pretty bad in googling stuff but ofcourse I got you guys!

Thanks for reply!

Comment: Search for dart spread operator it spreads the elements of the inner list to the outer list

Comment: Can you include a little more code-snippet about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [spread operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dart-spread-operator/), is used when you want to separate the items, imagine a situation that you want to join two lists:

```dart
List<int> a = [1, 2, 3];
List<int> b = [4, 5, 6];
```

If you just put them inside a list, you will get a List of lists.

```dart
List<int> combinedLists = [a, b];
// [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

But when you use spread operator, you will get the items out of list, like this:

```dart
List<int> combinedLists = [...a, ...b];
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```